# PHP DOM: rather newbie question

Tags: php, xml, dom

I've just started tinkering with XML manipulation with PHP, and i've stumbled into something unexpected. Here's the XML i'm using as a test input:

```
<list>
    <activity1> running </activity1>
    <activity2> swimming </activity2>
    <activity3> soccer </activity3>
</list>
```

Now, i was expecting that this PHP code would output 'activity1':

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('file.xml');

//the line below would make $root the <list> node
$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

//the line below would make $cnode the first child 
//of the <list> node, which is <activity1>
$cnode = $root->firstChild;

//this should output 'activity1'
echo 'element name: ' . $cnode->nodeName;
```

Instead, this code outputs #text. I could fix that by inserting a new line in the code, before printing the node name:

```
$cnode = $cnode->nextSibling;
```

Now, i would have expected that to print 'activity2' instead, but is printing 'activity1'. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The first *node* is the text (in this case whitespace) between the opening list tag and activity1 tag, the next *node* is the activity1 *element*. elements are not the same as nodes.

Answer (score 1):

To get the behaviour you expected, you need to pass in LIBXML_NOBLANKS as the second parameter of your load() call

```
<?php
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('file.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use XPath to query your document, you don't need to worry about this kind of arcana.  Use `DOMDocument::xpath_eval()` to evaluate the pattern `/list/*` and all you'll get back are the child elements of the top-level `list` element no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

A note on Czimi's answer: removing whitespace-only nodes will not prevent you from having to check the type of node (whether it is an element, a text node, a comment...). In general if you're interested in only selecting element nodes, you'll want to do something like this:

```
while($nodeInQuestion->nodeType != 1 && $nodeInQuestion->nextSibling) {
    $nodeInQuestion = $nodeInQuestion->nextSibling;
}
```

This is sort of pseudo-code. Obviously you'll need to handle failure somehow if you're looking for an element and reach the end of the parentNode's childNodes before you find it.